# Open Graph Facebook _ NextJS app : all my metadata appears on the page view source but Facebook complain that it found nothing

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, next.js

I have all my metadata in my NextJS app, they are put on the root page, so  the metatada appear well on my view source's page. But my Facebook open graph seems to don't reach them for an unknown reason to me.

Here my ReactJS:

```
<Head>
 <title> Test 02 </title> 
      <meta property="og:title" content="An awesome endless memories's title" /> 
      <meta property="og:url" content="somepath/digital-marketing/website-digital-gq" />
      <meta property="og:description" 
        content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the
           suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb" />
       <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />

      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_GB" />
      <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="cn_CN" />
      <meta property="og:image" content={localImage} />
      <meta property="og:image:width" content="1600" />
      <meta property="og:image:height" content="800" />
 </Head>
```

[Facebook's Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) returns me

> Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly
>
> provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. Missing
>   Properties The following required properties are missing: og:url,
>   og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
>
> Could Not Connect To Server Check that the webserver is running, and that there
>   are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.
>
> Curl Error Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)

Honestly, I don't have even the beginning of a clue on this story, really, if someone has any hint, would be great,
thanks

Comment: What is the link to the page you have problem with?

Comment: @WizKid Hi I prepare a new link and send you ASAP

Comment: Facebook's Open Graph crawler does not execute JavaScript - your React app is meaningless to it.

Comment: Here my link https://hoco-next.herokuapp.com/digital-marketing/website-digital-gq

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, even with the html rendered on server - or it is just for the SEO bots ? so how can I use Graph I assume there is a workaround for it. Also the headers are set for the HTML dynamically I assume since they appears on the view source in the HTML header part'

Comment: @HoCo_ That URL returns a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` header, which is probably part of your troubles. (Try `curl -I https://hoco-next.herokuapp.com/digital-marketing/website-digital-gq` to see for yourself...) Since you've got static rendering in place, fix the 404 and it may start working.

Comment: how it is possible it is displayed on my browser

Comment: I think I understand the problem, I have to display the URL of the page that displays the articles component directly, the root page as mentioned above. I think it is the bug

Answer (score 1):

Answer - thanks to the hints in the comments.

when you use some URI for your Facebook Open Graph, be sure to target a vali URL, seems to be exclusively the root page of your component in case of NextJS, other languages/libraries/framework could probably follow a similar pattern.

You can set it directly in the facebook sharing link  in your code as following:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[your_operational_url]
```

you are not obliged to encode the URL if I trust the result of my tests. So just the text of your URL should be enought.

Good builds.

Comment: You will want to encode the URL - an `&` in it would break things, for example. You *can* target a deep link, but your server needs to present the right HTML - no JavaScript - with a 2xx status code.